# Jekyll group collections with the same frontmatter property

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a [collection](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) of markdown files in an `_mycollection` folder, each with a frontmatter value like `category: category1`, `category: category2`, etc. Currently I am using the following code to print out the content of each item.

```
{% for c in site.mycollection %}
    <p>{{ c.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}}
```

What I need is to list all of these items under their categories, where items that share a category name go under the same category, like so:

> #### category1
>
> content from collection item 1 with "category1" in its frontmatter
> content from collection item 4 with "category1" in its frontmatter
> content from collection item 5 with "category1" in its frontmatter
>
> #### category2
>
> content from collection item 2 with "category2" in its frontmatter
> content from collection item 3 with "category2" in its frontmatter

I am looking for how I can modify the code I mentioned above so that it includes a single heading for each category name and then places each collection item with that category under its respective category heading.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting output using Liquid's `group_by` filter.

```
{% for c in site.mycollection %}
    <p>{{ c.content | group_by: "category" }}</p>
{% endfor %}}
```